# Instantiating a Java local class reflectively

Tags: java, reflection

In Java, is there a way or hack to instantiate a [local class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) reflectively?

This is my test class:

```
package com.example.localclass;

import org.junit.Test;

public class LocalClassInstantiationTest {

    @Test
    public void testInstantiateLocalClassReflectively() {
        System.out.println("About to define local class");
        class LocalClass {
            void print() {
                System.out.println("Hello world");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("--------------------Direct instantiation------------------------");
        LocalClass localClassInstance;
        localClassInstance = new LocalClass();
        localClassInstance.print();

        System.out.println("--------------------Reflective instantiation--------------------");
        Class<LocalClass> localClazz = LocalClass.class;
        System.out.println("Local class name: " + localClazz.getName() );
        System.out.println("Local class canonical name: " + localClazz.getCanonicalName() );
        System.out.println("Local class constructors array length: " + localClazz.getConstructors().length);
        System.out.println("About to create local class instance reflectively");

        try {
            localClassInstance = localClazz.newInstance();
            localClassInstance.print();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

When I run it, I get the following result:

```
About to define local class
--------------------Direct instantiation------------------------
Hello world
--------------------Reflective instantiation--------------------
Local class name: com.example.localclass.LocalClassInstantiationTest$1LocalClass
Local class canonical name: null
Local class constructors array length: 0
About to create local class instance reflectively
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.localclass.LocalClassInstantiationTest$1LocalClass
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at com.example.localclass.LocalClassInstantiationTest.testInstantiateLocalClassReflectively(LocalClassInstantiationTest.java:32)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, the problem is that there is no empty constructor for your class.  The newInstance() assumes you have one and fails if you don't.

If you run this in a static method such as main, you don't get this error.

This is because you have a non-static anonymous class and implicitly requires a reference to your outer class LocalClassInstantiationTest whether you use it or not.

You could try this instead.

```
System.out.println("Local class constructors array length: " + 
                   localClazz.getDeclaredConstructors().length);
System.out.println("About to create local class instance reflectively");

try {
    localClassInstance = localClazz
            .getDeclaredConstructor(LocalClassInstantiationTest.class)
            .newInstance(this);
    localClassInstance.print();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and your program prints

```
About to define local class
--------------------Direct instantiation------------------------
Hello world
--------------------Reflective instantiation--------------------
Local class name: LocalClassInstantiationTest$1LocalClass
Local class canonical name: null
Local class constructors array length: 1
About to create local class instance reflectively
Hello world
```

Comment: So with inner classes, there's an implicit first parameter to all constructors with which the containing instance is passed?

Comment: @Bohemian correct.  It is a problem with Serialization as well as you can try to serialize the outer class, which is a pain if you are not even using it.

Comment: Well you got my +1 already, but I didn't know that! Interesting. Thanks for posting! :)

Comment: I could try it myself, but is it the case that that parameter is only available reflectively? ie one couldn't invoke it in code as `new InnerClass(outerInstance)` as an alternative to `outerInstance.new InnerClass()`? If so, that's really *quite* interesting.

Comment: I just realised Duh - this is completely obvious. It's the same paradigm as invoking a method reflectively by passing the instance as the first parameter. It's the only way that makes sense. It's slightly interesting only in the it's a *constructor* that's invoked like a method, or simply the realisation that constructors *are* methods.

Comment: `newInstance()` for local classes take as many parameters are there're closure references, even when inside a static `main()`, making them rather difficult to instantiate for the general case.  Inner classes are by far easier, taking only that extra single enclosing class instance as the first parameter.